# What does "Object" mean in E[] temp = (E[]) new Object[capacity]

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, object, generics

I'm look at dynamic arrays and I'm not sure what "Object" means for

```
protected void resize (int capacity) {

E[] temp = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
    temp[k] = data[k];
    data = temp;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every class has `Object` as a superclass, i.e. even if you write something like:

```
class A {}
```

then `A` implicitly extends `Object`. Because of this we can use variables of type `Object` to store any type:

```
Object x = new SomeClass();
```

and then to cast to the type we need when reading:

```
SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass) x;
```

Now, since we can not construct generic arrays, i.e. we can't do `new T[]`, the only solution is to construct an "universal" (that can contain any type) array `new Object[]` and then to cast to the type wee need.

Answer (score 0):

Its the root object that everything else derives from : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Most IDE's enable you to click through and see the implmentation (ie ctrl+click on Object, and it will take you to its definition).

A new array of objects is being created, then casted (which is lame).

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is the root of all classes in Java. In this case it is just being used to allocate memory for the references of whatever objects are stored in that array. You can store any type of Object in that array and cast it to another type at runtime like `(MyClass) temp[3];`

Answer (score 0):

Since all objects extend Object this is just creating an array that can hold anything, so we copy all the contents of "data" one by one, and it doesn't matter what type they are since each item will definitely extend Object. Since you can't instantiate generic types (ie. `new E[]()`) you must use a type you *can* instantiate and cast to the generic - we can instantiate Object and cast to E safely.

Answer (score 0):

"Object" means the Object class.  In java, all other classes in inherit from the Object class.  So, here you are declaring an array of any java type.